# Is the group $(\Bbb Z,+)$ isomorphic to the the group $(\Bbb Q\setminus\{0\},\cdot)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

Is the group $(\Bbb Z,+)$ isomorphic to the the group $(\Bbb Q\setminus\{0\},\cdot)$?

Comment: No. Try looking for a generator of the latter.

Comment: Being cyclic is a group invariant.

Answer (score 2):

No. $(\Bbb Z, +)$ is generated by $\{1,-1\}$ and $(\Bbb Q^\times, \cdot)$ is not finitely generated.

Comment: Shouldn't $\{1\}$ be enough to generate $(\Bbb{Z},+)$ as a group? After all, if a group contains $1$, it must contain $-1$, too.

Answer (score 2):

They are not isomorphic. In $(\mathbb Q\setminus \{0\},\cdot)$ you have an element that is its own inverse $(-1)$. This does not happen in $(\mathbb Z,+)$

Comment: Do you mean an element different from the identity, right? :)

Comment: Yes I do, thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "own inverse"?

Comment: An element of $x$ a group $(G,*)$ is its own inverse if $x*x=e$ (where $e$ is the identity).

Comment: Yes, but if $x$ is in $Q$ then how is $x*x=e$. i.e. $\frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{2}$ doesn't equal $1$

Comment: Not every element is its own inverse, just $-1$, since $(-1)(-1)=1$.

Comment: but $-1$ doesn't exist in $Q$ does it? it is not a fraction.